postgresql.query without sql statements in datadog
I have an issue in my SpringBoot project. If an endpoint is hit, it will go through my logic and execute an postgresql query and return the results. In these, for some of the requests, while executing queries it takes time. Then when i saw in my datadog traces, before executing my query or simultaneously, there are one or two query named "postgresql.query", which is getting executed. There is no sql statement mentioned for those, its just "postgresql.query". I wanna know what are these queries named "postgresql.query" and why those are getting executed? And also due to which, i am getting org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: An I/O error occurred while sending to the backend, why am I getting this error in 5 seconds, whereas my connection-timeout is 2min and idle-timeout is 10sec?
This is my database config,
datasource:
type: com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource
hikari:
  minimum-idle: 2
  maximum-pool-size: 5
  idle-timeout: 10000 #10s
  pool-name: my-hikari-pool
  connection-timeout: 120000 #2m
  max-lifetime: 180000 #3m

